# Get images sources from string and display them in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imagesource

I am using recyclerview to display images ( in drawable folder ), it's just an exercice and I have an arraylist of three object ( ImageModel ), each ImageModel has a field, I am calling it image ( String ), the ImageModel has its constuctor and getters and setters ( very basic class ), ..

Now I am displaying three images blocks with the same image, I am using the image id to display it, image.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage); but I want to display multiple images based on the image field ( url  or part of the url )

This is my class Adapter, go the the last 10 lines to see my problem, not a problem actually but I don't know how to make it dynamic, because I have three Image models now, I may have 5, maybe 20, I don't know ..

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

    public List<ImageModel> images = new ArrayList<ImageModel>();
    public Context context;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, List<ImageModel> contracts){
        this.context = context;
        this.images.clear();
        this.images.addAll(contracts);
        Log.d("TAG", "ADAPTER");
    }

    public void updateImages(List<ImageModel> newImages){
        images.clear();
        images.addAll(newImages);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false); // ContratBinding >> as your list item layout named "contrat"
        return new ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageListAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.images.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.img)
        ImageView image;

        public ImageViewHolder(View iview){
            super(iview);
            Log.d("TAG", "VIEW HOLDER");
            ButterKnife.bind(this, iview);
        }
        void bind(ImageModel imageModel){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
        }
    }


}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Add Picasso dependency in build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

> Then implement the code inside your bind function

```
void bind(ImageModel imageModel)
{

   Picasso.get().load(your_image_url_string).into(image);
}
```

Comment: No, I don't have the whole url, as I said my pics are in drawable folder, image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg etc .. and my string are something like this image1, image2, imgae3, ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another field as Id(Int) in ImageModel and add your image source id (R.drawable.image1) in your list.

ImageModel(**id=** R.drawable.image1, **image=** image1)

```
 void bind(ImageModel imageModel){
            image.setImageResource(imageModel.id);
        }
```

Or if you are adding your image source name in the string variable **image** in ImageModel, then you can get the image from drawable dynamically as below

ImageModel(**image=** image1)

```
 void bind(ImageModel imageModel){
       String uri = "@drawable/"+imageModel.image; //don't use extension like .png or .jpg
       int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,getPackageName());
       Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
       image.setImageDrawable(res);
   }
```

Comment: getResources method is not known, I can not import it, why is that ? do I need to activate something in my build.gradleor something ?

Comment: Method to be used in Adapter, so use context.getResources(). you cannot directly get resources in adapter. Updated the code above